# Changes in one Cosmos DB partition going to multiple Azure function instances

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

We have an Azure function with a Cosmos DB trigger that needs to process items within a partition sequentially, but not in any specific order.  My understanding is the trigger will always send all changes for a partition to one function instance at a time.  However, I am seeing changes for one partition being processed by multiple function instances within a few seconds.  So the change feed distribution to function instances is not working as I expect it to.

This function app runs on the latest V2 function host.  The function is a durable function.  We use a 'leases' collection with a specific prefix to manage the leases for this change feed.

```
[FunctionName("ProcessChanges")]
public static async Task RunAsync([CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "MyDatabase",
    collectionName: "MyCollection",
    ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureWebJobsCosmosDBConnectionString",
    LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
    LeaseCollectionPrefix = "chgproc",
    CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents,
    [OrchestrationClient]DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    // Processing code that calls the orchestrator function
}
```

I expect all changes for a given partition at a given time to go to one function instance, but sometimes they go to multiple function instances.

Comment: A lease can only be owned by 1 instance at a time. Each lease represents a Partition Key Range, not a physical partition. You can verify this on your leases collection with the Owner property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-changefeed-functions#some-changes-are-missing-in-my-trigger. Do you have multiple Triggers with different LeaseCollectionPrefix values by any chance like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-create-multiple-cosmos-db-triggers ?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Yes, we have two different triggers on this collection and each one has a different LeaseCollectionPrefix.

Comment: That means that each change in your collection will be sent once to each Function, and thus, land in two instances (in your case because you have 2 Functions). The goal of the LeaseCollectionPrefix is to allow different independent Functions to process changes independently and in parallel. Were you expecting a change to be processed by both Functions in parallel?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I'm good with the two different functions processing the same document change at the same time.  The issue I'm experiencing is when document A in partition A is processed by the MyFunc function on one function instance and document B in partition A is processed by the MyFunc function on a different function instance within one second.  I need these two documents that are in the same partition to be processed sequentially by the MyFunc function.

Comment: When you mean Partition, are you meaning Partition Key Value? Do both documents have the same Partition Key Value (the value in the attribute marked as Partition Key Path during your collection creation)? How are you asserting that these are different instances?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Yes, that's what I mean.  Both documents have the same partition key value.  I used Application Insights traces to determine the function instance (cloud_RoleInstance) used for each execution of the function.  When I state that the changed documents with the same partition key are being processed on different function instances at a given time, I am basing that on the cloud_RoleInstance values being different in the traces.

Comment: Do each of your Function use different App Insights? Could there be a scaling operation happening? You could see if another instance took ownership of the partition by checking the [logs](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/azure-cosmos-db-functions-cookbook-shared-throughput-and-new-health-logs-818bc0591dd6). If one instance was processing one batch that included document A, that batch finished, a scaling happened and that lease was transferred to another instance, and the next batch containing doc B could be processed by the new instance. Docs could be in separate batches.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I think you are exactly right regarding what is happening with batches and how that affects my issue.  I will enable trigger logging and add more tracing to confirm how this is working.  I have been focused on what is happening in the activity function, but the change feed is actually linked to the durable orchestration client function so there is a potential delay between incoming change feed changes vs. activity function execution.  Your Medium posts are really awesome and I appreciate all the information you have shared.  Thanks so much for your prompt responses here.

Comment: Glad to help. I never tried the Trigger with Durable Functions, so maybe the orchestrator is just scaling instances. In any case, even across different instances, the changes are received in order (doc A before doc B), relying on the same instance to receive the changes on a serverless environment might not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation on how the distribution actually should work, do you have the source of that?

Does your leases collection have the `/id` partition, as is mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions#requirements)?

> The lease container: The lease container maintains state across multiple and dynamic serverless Azure Function instances and enables dynamic scaling. This lease container can be manually or automatically created by the Azure Cosmos DB Trigger.To automatically create the lease container, set the CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists flag in the configuration. **Partitioned lease containers are required to have a /id partition key definition.**

Comment: That's a good point.  My leases collection does not have a partition key.  It was created by having the CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists flag set to true in the function trigger definition.  I have wondered if this is the problem.  Do I need to manually create the leases collection with the /id partition key?  I don't think I've come across documentation regarding what specifications are applied when the leases collection is created automatically via the CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists flag, so it would be helpful if that information was available.

Comment: Partition Key is unrelated to the question. `/id` partition key is only required if your leases collection is partitioned, if it's not partitioned, that requirement is not valid. So, basically, use a non-partitioned lease collection OR use a partitioned lease collection with `/id` as partition key path.